# How to configure rate limit for a specific api action based on server response?

Tags: limit, azure-api-management, rate

Is there a way to configure rate limit rule on a ***specific*** API action on Azure API management. The desired solution is to return HTTP 429 (too many request) if the end user receives a certain response from the backend, after X attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See increment-condition on rate-limit-by-key policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#LimitCallRateByKey

Answer (score 0):

In Azure APIM, rate limiting can be done based on a key or subscription. So rate limit based on the back end response over a number of times is not possible.

It is also not a good practice to keep track of response status between the calls.

You can possibly make use of retry policy to verify the response from back end service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#Retry. You can use the retry result to send back 429 response.